How to create a custom Ubuntu 24.04.1 image by using xorriso?
I am trying to create a custom Ubuntu server image by using xorriso, I have download the base image, extract the files from it, edit the grub file to start from nocloud and add my custom user-data and meta-data files.
Then I tried to rebuild it by using xorriso like:
xorriso -as mkisofs \
   -r -V "Ubuntu 24.04.01" \
   -o ~/ubuntu-vortex-24.04.iso \
   -J -l \
   -c boot.catalog \
   -b boot/grub/i386-pc/eltorito.img \
   -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table \
   -eltorito-alt-boot -e EFI/boot/grubx64.efi \
   -no-emul-boot -isohybrid-gpt-basdat \
   ~/ubuntu-vortex

When I try to run the installation I get stuck here:

The user-data:
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  locale: it_IT.UTF-8
  keyboard:
    layout: us
  network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
      eth0:
        dhcp4: false
        addresses:
          - 192.168.1.137/24
        gateway4: 192.168.1.1
        nameservers:
          addresses:
            - 8.8.8.8
  ssh:
    install-server: true
    allow-pw: true
  storage:
    layout:
      name: direct
  timezone: Europe/Rome
  packages:
    - openssh-server
    - docker.io
    - docker-compose-v2
  package_update: true
  package_upgrade: true
  user-data:
    users:
      - name: administrator
        passwd: "$6$gRuzUReTpyqPxFly$7eAKV/NHQ3TpUAi44YJ8A4IEriUgN2e7tgFWvJFrtEJgiRR.Ydb0OZBSEhcqh/lk2/3NQ913mUxB3ewQxcpIa/"
        groups: [ adm, sudo, docker ]
        lock_passwd: false
        shell: /bin/bash
        sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    # Add runcmd to run Docker login and Docker Compose during the first boot
    runcmd:
      # Docker login using username and access token
      - echo "password" | docker login -u "user" --password-stdin

      # Move to the application directory and run Docker Compose
      - cd /opt/app && docker compose up -d
  late-commands:
    # Enable the initialize_device.service so it runs on the first boot
    - "systemctl enable initialize-device.service"  

The grub has been customized like:
linux /casper/vmlinuz autoinstall ds=nocloud; ---
initrd /casper/initrd


Are you having trouble building the new ISO or trouble with booting from the ISO and installing the OS? I'm confused, because you say you "tried to rebuild" the ISO, but then later state, "try to run the installation". Please edit/update your question with this info. Also, please add the contents of your user-data, meta-data, and grub files. Finally, please indicate the exact ISO you're starting with.

Close voters should note that this question deals with modifications to Ubuntu 24.04.01 and is thus on topic here...

@mpboden I've just add user-data and the grub the meta-data is just empty. The trouble is when I'm booting from the new ISO and installing the OS.

I think the error message you're getting, "Unable to find a medium containing a live file system", is due to a mis-configured grub.cfg file and possibly a faulty bootable USB flash device.
When I attempt to install a custom ISO on a VirualBox VM using your user-data and grub.cfg files, I see an entirely different error message right at the beginning of the boot process. So let's fix your grub.cfg file.
I'm using the following ISO for testing: ubuntu-24.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso
Test installs with VirtualBox Version 7.0.20 r163906.

Currently you have the following for your menuentry:
linux /casper/vmlinuz autoinstall ds=nocloud; ---
initrd /casper/initrd

There are actually two problems here, but the first is you're not escaping the semi-colon. As a result, the rest of the line is treated as a comment, and the error message I see is the following:
error: can't find command '---'.

But since you're not seeing this, it leads me to believe that you either have a faulty bootable USB flash drive or the boot process is different on a bare metal server.
So the first fix is to escape the semi-colon with a backslash as follows:
linux /casper/vmlinuz autoinstall ds=nocloud\; ---
initrd /casper/initrd

Now if that was the only fix you made to grub.cfg and you were able to successfully boot, you'd quickly discover that your autoinstall directives would be overlooked. This is due to the second problem in your grub.cfg file.
You've indicated ds=nocloud as your data source, but you haven't told autoinstall where to look for the necessary files. (Additionally, you haven't told us where you've put them either.) But typically, they'll be in a top-level directory of your extracted ISO, something like nocloud. Therefore, you also need to add something like s=/cdrom/nocloud to your menuentry kernel command:
linux /casper/vmlinuz autoinstall ds=nocloud\;s=/cdrom/nocloud ---
initrd /casper/initrd

This tells autoinstall to look in a directory called nocloud in the top level of the "CDROM", which is your USB flash drive. Of course, both files, user-data and meta-data need to be in this directory. See below:
$ tree -L 2
.
├── boot
│   ├── grub
│   └── memtest86+x64.bin
├── boot.catalog
├── casper
│   ├── filesystem.manifest
│   ├── filesystem.size
│   ├── initrd
│   ├── install-sources.yaml
│   ├── ubuntu-server-minimal.manifest
│   ├── ubuntu-server-minimal.size
│   ├── ubuntu-server-minimal.squashfs
│   ├── ubuntu-server-minimal.squashfs.gpg
│   ├── ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.generic.manifest
│   ├── ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.generic.size
│   ├── ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.generic.squashfs
│   ├── ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.generic.squashfs.gpg
│   ├── ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.manifest
│   ├── ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.size
│   ├── ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.squashfs
│   ├── ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.squashfs.gpg
│   ├── ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.manifest
│   ├── ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.size
│   ├── ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.squashfs
│   ├── ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.squashfs.gpg
│   └── vmlinuz
├── dists
│   ├── noble
│   ├── stable -> noble
│   └── unstable -> noble
├── EFI
│   └── boot
├── install
├── md5sum.txt
├── nocloud
│   ├── meta-data
│   └── user-data
├── pool
│   ├── main
│   └── restricted
└── ubuntu -> .


Aside from this, your user-data file is correct except that your late command fails to enable a systemd service called initialize-device.service. I'm not sure if you have this configured in some other way, but by default there isn't a service with this name.
Finally, your xorriso command to create the ISO works successfully and isn't the source of your problem.

So in conclusion, I would make these corrections to grub.cfg first to see if it corrects your problem. If not, then I'd revisit your procedure on how you made your USB flash drive.
